# Elements of Algebra (Euler) in comparison to similar texts

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

I have no problem with *Elements of Algebra* simply because of its age; in fact, I strongly agree with Abel's famous assertion regarding the proper place to look for knowledge.

What do you guys think about *Elements of Algebra*, in particular, and texts covering similar material in general?

Comment: This strikes me as being very subjective and open for this forum.

Comment: What's wrong with a subjective question about a mathematics book that directly relates to the history of mathematics, a question of the sort "welcomed" (as the third bullet point in the introductory portion of the faq will tell you)?
Considering the fact that threads discussing the question of [reading from the "masters"](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28268/do-you-read-the-masters) are welcomed on MathOverflow I think a question discussing this, "and texts covering similar material in general" should be welcomed & not modded out of history...

Comment: @mixedmath, my question is mainly about a specific text by a specific author (and what an author he was!). Is a question "very subjective and open" because there is less of a chance that you can reply using LaTeX? If you know nothing of the book I mention, and are uninterested, then you are free to ignore the question. :)

Comment: I didn't say that this question was wrong for this forum, simply that it was poorly suited for this forum. In short, it is a discussion question, and this is not a discussion forum (@sponsoredwalk similarly found within the faq). Note also that I am not closing it, attempting to close it, or encouraging others to close it.

Comment: @mixedmath, well, I'll be able to ask much more localised questions as I progress mathematically. At this point in time, I want perspectives on the materials I'm looking into, so as to not waste any time :) "look before you leap" sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer: read euler.   E.g. would you recommend reading Shakespeare's Hamlet, or the Classics comics version?

I think Euler is probably the best introductory algebra book in existence.  I would recommend it for all gifted high school students.

Comment: Disagree. Old mathematics texts are often "boring". Try reading papers of Lagrange in Number Theory before Gauss, or Descartes' La Geometrie.

Comment: Have you tried reading Euler?

Comment: Your analogy is flawed. (E.g. would you recommend reading Shakespeare's *Hamlet*, or Dickens's *Bleak House*, or Joyce's *Ulysses*, or Chaucer's *Canterbury Tales*? Time is limited, and it depends on the reader.) Yes classics are good to read, and Euler is great, but one can't read them all. Why not read Al-Khwarizmi's *Kitab al-Jabr…* or Chrystal's *Algebra* or Bhaskara's *Bijaganita* or Diophantus's *Arithmetica*, other classics on algebra? Or read Euler's classic *Introductio…* instead? Etc. :) An author may be great but whether a specific book is worth reading is not a foregone conclusion.